# PHP + SQLite3 Get the page based on a nickname

Tags: php, database, sqlite

```
I have the following code:

        $limit = 20;
        if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
        if ($page > $pagecount) $page = $pagecount;
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        $db = new SQLite3($serverpath . "Database/eo.s3db");
        $results = $db->querySingle('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM achievement_' . $name);
        $pagecount = ceil($results/$limit);

        $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM achievement_' . $name . ' ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset);
```

Which will get the data needed from a table just fine, based on page. (I know offset needs changing as it's slow apparently, which I will be doing!)
This returns a nickname, rank, and amount (sorted by amount.)

The issue comes from understanding how to get a page based on nickname and get the data around that. I.E. If I say I want to get the name BOB and hes on page 55 -- I would have to first find BOB and determine what page hes on. The rest I can handle myself as I would know what to do with a page number. The problem is determining what page he'd be based on the limit (20) per page above and the amount it's sorted on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"BOB" is on page

```
SELECT (count(*) / $limit) + 1 
FROM achievment 
amount > (SELECT amount from achievement where name = "BOB")
```